# How to display File(C#) in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, file, model-view-controller

How can I display in javasctipt site this File (c#)?

```
return File(streams.First(), "application/octet-stream", Path.GetFileName(element.Path));
```

I want something like this :

```
            <img id="myImg" src="_____" width="107" height="98">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to download the image with Javascript and convert it to a urlObject. You can use this function to do so:

```js
function toDataUrl(url, callback) {
     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     request.responseType = "blob";
     request.onload = function() {
       document.getElementById("myImg").src = URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
     }
     request.open("GET", "/path/to/image/file");
     request.send();
}
```